# JUnit RunListener is removed on fail()

Tags: java, junit, listener

I am using a [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) to let test fail when they write to System.out, but when I fail() a unittest, the listener is removed. Is there any way to let tests fail without removing the Listener?

For clarification a code example

```
public class OutputListenerTest {
  @Test
  public void testPrintIsDicovered() {
    JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
    // the OutputListener calls fail() when something was written
    runner.addListener(new OutputListener());
    Result result = runner.run(TestWithOutput.class);
  }

  public static class TestWithOutput {
    @Test
    public void testOutput1() {
      System.out.println("foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOutput2() {
      System.out.println("bar");
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd expect: 2 failed tests
What is: The first test fails and the Listener is removed.

As requested, here is the OutputListener code http://paste.robbi5.com/4916ca5b
Is it ok to not paste it here, it's pretty long and won't help solving the question?

**a little more context**
I picked the RunListener, because it works pretty easy with maven, just add

```
  <properties>
    <property>
      <name>listener</name>
      <value>OutputListener</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
```

to the maven-surefire-plugin and `mvn test` shows what tests use System.out in some way.

Comment: Personally, I would probably simply add a custom TestRule... Should work to wrap the actual in a Verifier to check the Output.

Comment: I've created this example and the my listener isn't removed, so I would look at your listener code. Can you supply it?

Comment: Apidoc says "If a listener throws an exception while processing a test event, it will be removed for the remainder of the test run." And when debug and step through the tests, removeListener is called. So I am pretty sure the Listener is removed :)

Comment: So the problem, as I suggested, is the the listener. If the listener does not throw an exception it will continue for all tests.

Comment: but how do i let the listener fail the test without throwing an exeption? fail() throws an AssertionException

Comment: listeners, listen, they don't (or shouldn't) interact with the test.

Comment: well, now there's a totally different question to be answered: how do I fail test who write to sysout? If I can't use Listeners? I guess I'm back to the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92707/discussion-between-dom-farr-and-globalworming).

Comment: general question if this is the best way to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214683/fail-tests-on-write-to-system-out-or-err

Answer (score 1):

Add a Runner to add the listener.

```
public class AddListenerRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public AddListenerRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override public void run(RunNotifier notifier){
        notifier.addListener(new OutputListener());
        super.run(notifier);
    }
}
```

You can then use that in your tests like this.

```
@RunWith(AddListenerRunner.class)
public class OutputListenerTest {
    @Test
    public void testOutput1() {
      System.out.println("foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOutput2() {
      System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: um.. wouldn't that result in a lot of the same Listeners when the tests don't fail? Also I would prefer a solution where I don't have to change every testclass I've got. Your approach is basically right, overriding the run method would work.

Comment: "Opt-in by default" would be a much more preferable solution to the problem. If it is required to add an annotation for nearly all test cases, an explicit opt-out to the default opt-in is the better approach.