# Fail tests on write to System.out or .err

Tags: java, maven, junit, continuous-integration

I'd like my CI build to fail when the tests write something to System.out or System.err. Preferably I would like to have a list of tests which produced unwanted output.

I tried to use mavens surefire plugin with an added listener, but that does only part of the trick as you can see from the question [JUnit RunListener is removed on fail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207996/junit-runlistener-is-removed-on-fail)

Did someone else try something like this and are there other ways to achieve a cleaner console on CI builds?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at this Maven plugin `https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis` which check for forbidden API calls. You can define wich calls should be forbidden in the code.

**edit** Simple example to show exclusion of not permitted api calls. In the example the call of `System.out.println` should not be permitted in test classes with the exception of one test class.

`pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.thetaphi</groupId>
            <artifactId>forbiddenapis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>testCheck</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <signaturesFiles>
                    <signaturesFile>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/signatures.txt</signaturesFile>
                </signaturesFiles>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- specify the classes which should be excluded -->
                    <exclude>**/Permitted*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The signatur file `src\test\resources\signatures.txt`

```
java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)
```

Test classes

```
// the one which doesn't use System.out
package sub.optimal;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
public class NoSystemOutTest {
    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getGlobal();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "some info");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

.

```
// the one in which the use of System.out should be permitted
package sub.optimal;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
public class PermittedSystemOutTest {
    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        System.out.println("permitted usage");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

.

```
// the one in which the use of System.out is not permitted
package sub.optimal;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
public class NotPermittedSystemOutTest {
    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        System.out.println("not permitted usage");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Running the check with `mvn test-compile forbiddenapis:testCheck` will only report the forbidden api usage in `NotPermittedSystemOutTest`.

```
[ERROR] Forbidden method invocation: java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   in sub.optimal.NotPermittedSystemOutTest (NotPermittedSystemOutTest.java:9)
```

Comment: I'm a colleague of globalwarming. Our problem is that there are some valid cases where calling `System.out`/`.err` is a valid case.

Comment: @user3001 Please check the added example how to exclude a class from the check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Checkstyle plugin so that your test with unwanted code fails and will be listed as failed in surfire reports.

Comment: There are parts in our project which do use System.out.print and that's ok. This is just for keeping the `mvn test` output clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a test writes to `System.out` by using the library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/)

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

  @After
  public void assertNoTextHasBeenWrittenToSystemOut() {
    assertEquals("", systemOutRule.getLog())
  }

  ...
}
```

There same may be done with `System.err` by using the `SystemErrRule`.

Comment: Need your help at [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712632/systemoutrule-in-junit-test-didnt-capture-standard-output) :)