# SystemOutRule in JUnit test didn't capture standard output

Tags: java, junit, io, junit5

I want to test `ClientDtoServiceConsoleImpl.displayAllClientsInfo()` method. It simply prints some data to console.

I tried to capture output in unit test by [`SystemOutRule`](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html#SystemErrAndOutRule), but got empty `String output`. **Why?**

```
package com.example.services.dto;
import com.example.dtos.AccountDTO;
import com.example.dtos.ClientDTO;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.SystemOutRule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest {
    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule systemOutput = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    void displayAllClientsInfo() {
        // Given
        List<ClientDTO> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        clients.add(new ClientDTO(1L, "John Smith", "client@example.com", Arrays.asList(
                new AccountDTO(10L, 1L, "JSmith1","zzwvp0d9", LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59) ),
                new AccountDTO(20L, 1L, "JSmith2","mhjnbgfv", LocalDateTime.of(2016,1,5,18,32) ),
                new AccountDTO(30L, 1L, "JSmith3","ytersds1", LocalDateTime.of(2015,11,10,11,29) )
                )));
        clients.add(new ClientDTO(2L, "Jack Black", "jack@example.com", new ArrayList<>()));
        ClientDtoService clientDtoService = new ClientDtoServiceConsoleImpl();

        // When
        clientDtoService.displayAllClientsInfo(clients);

        // Then
        String output = systemOutput.getLog();
        assertAll(
                // Client
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(1))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("client@example.com")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("John Smith")),
                // Accounts
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(10))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith1")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("zzwvp0d9")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59).toString())),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(20))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith2")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("mhjnbgfv")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(LocalDateTime.of(2016,1,5,18,32).toString())),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(30))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith3")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("ytersds1")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(LocalDateTime.of(2015,11,10,11,29).toString())),
                // Client
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(2))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("jack@example.com")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("Jack Black"))
        );
    }
}
```

---

[image: in debugging]

---

`displayAllClientsInfo(List<ClientDTO> clients)` has *approximately* the following structure:

```
for (ClientDTO client : clients) {
    System.out.println(client.getName());
    List<AccountDTO> accounts = client.getAccounts();
    for (AccountDTO account : accounts){
        System.out.println(account.getLogin());
    }
}
```

---

When I manually change system output by `System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStream))` and then use for testing `outputStream.toString()` — test works good.

---

Begin of console output:

```
                        Clients                                                              Accounts                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id                   e-mail                     name | id                       created                    login                 password
============================================================================================================================================
    1       client@example.com               John Smith |
                                                        | 10              2017-05-25T12:59                  JSmith1                 zzwvp0d9
                                                        | 20              2016-01-05T18:32                  JSmith2                 mhjnbgfv
                                                        | 30              2015-11-10T11:29                  JSmith3                 ytersds1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2         jack@example.com               Jack Black |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:48)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:54)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:33)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:110)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.lambda$displayAllClientsInfo$0(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.lambda$assertAll$0(AssertAll.java:57)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:1039)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.displayAllClientsInfo(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:48)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:54)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:33)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:110)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.lambda$displayAllClientsInfo$1(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.lambda$assertAll$0(AssertAll.java:57)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:1039)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.displayAllClientsInfo(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:48)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:54)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:33)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:110)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.lambda$displayAllClientsInfo$2(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:75)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.lambda$assertAll$0(AssertAll.java:57)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:44)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(Assertions.java:1039)
    at com.example.services.dto.ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.displayAllClientsInfo(ClientDtoServiceConsoleImplTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Comrades, could [**this**](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/780) be the problem?

Comment: @eee Thanks for link. Googling did not help. As I understand there are no `Extension` for `SystemOutRule`... :(

Comment: @eee You can post answer, I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules are from the JUnit 4 world. In JUnit 5 (or to be more precise JUnit Jupiter) Rules are silently ignored. [You need an `Extension` and annotate the test class or method with `ExtendWith`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions).

The author of the `SystemOutRule` [intends to port the rule to an extension](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules/issues/55).

---

**Update:**

There is an [extension](https://github.com/sbrannen/junit5-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/extensions/CaptureSystemOutput.java) by a JUnit 5 core commiter.

Comment: Am I correct that the extension mentioned above isn't anywhere in maven central? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `static` modifier on SystemOutRule

```
public final SystemOutRule systemOutput = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();
```

Comment: First time it was without `static`. It's still not working. Maybe there are no  support for JUnit 5?

Comment: That would be my guess - JUnit 5 is pretty new.

Comment: I noticed in another post that there appears to be a JUnit5 tag now, it might help to add it to your post.